# What is an upright rectangle?

Tags: terminology, computational-geometry

What is an upright rectangle?

I came across the phrase in my homework -

"The bounding box of a set of S points is the smallest upright rectangle containing S. Describe and analyze an algorithm to compute the bounding box of n points in the plane using fewer than 3n comparisons."

Can anyone explain to me what is meant by an upright rectangle?

Comment: One question per question, please.  I've edited the question to focus on one question.  If you get that answered, you should be able to figure out what is meant by "the smallest rectangle that contains S" on your own.  Anyway: have you asked your TA or instructor?  They should be your first point of contact.  They're more likely to know what they meant than some random person on the rectangle.   We can give you a guess, but they can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it means an axis-aligned rectangle, i.e., a rectangle whose bottom edge is horizontal (parallel to the $x$-axis) and whose left edge is vertical (parallel to the $y$-axis).  This is the standard meaning of "bounding box".  For future reference, before asking it is useful to check Wikipedia and search thoroughly.  In this case you would have found lots of information on the phrase "bounding box": see, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle

Comment: People ask questions on stack overflow because other sources are inadequate at explaining things. The wiki link that you shared does not explains what an upright rectangle is. And if you google "upright rectangle" you will see why I decided to ask this question on this site.

Comment: @akshayrajkore, sure, but try googling "bounding box".

Comment: I did. And it did not explain what an "upright rectangle" is.

Comment: @akshayrajkore, what I'm saying is: once you understand what the standard definition of bounding box is, (a) you don't need to know what a upright rectangle is, and (b) it's not too hard to work out what the definition of upright rectangle must be, given the quote you gave us.  By the way, this isn't Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

[image: boxes vs non-boxes]

(Yes, today I had nothing better to do)